# How to find the position with if-statement in column in PowerBI/Dax

Tags: find, position, powerbi, dax

My simplified datasetlooks like:

```
Step Position Value  
A   1   1  
A   2   0  
A   3   1  
A   4   1  
A   5   1  
A   6   1  
B   1   1  
B   2   0  
B   3   1  
B   4   1  
B   5   0  
B   6   1
```

I would like to know for each step how many zero's I have and at what position.

I could make a table like this:

```
Step      Countzero  
A          1  
B          2
```

by using this code:

```
CountZero = COUNTX ( FILTER ( 'Table'; 'Table'[Value] == 0 ); 'Table'[Value] )
```

How can I determine at what positions these zeros occur?

This could, for instance, be presented in a table like the one below, but any other form of presentation would do too.

```
Step     Position of zero  
A        2  
B        2, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCATENATEX` similarly to how you're using `COUNTX`:

```
PositionZero =
CONCATENATEX ( FILTER ( 'Table'; 'Table'[Value] = 0 ); 'Table'[Position]; "," )
```

Comment: And you can use the left function to remove the comma at the end ;)

Comment: The `CONCATENATEX` function doesn't leave a comma at the end, just between items.